# Is there way to use smartphone camera in PhoneJS?

Tags: android-camera, phonejs

I am trying to build test app with PhoneJS for Android. But I can not find a way how to use a camera. 
Is it possible at all? Or better switch to PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Welcome to PhoneJS!](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/BlogPost/welcome-to-phonejs) article:

> With Apache Cordova (or Adobe PhoneGap) you have the capability to compile those apps to real mobile apps that can access the native platform (the camera, accelerometer, GPS, etc)

PhoneJS does not have its own interface to the device hardware, but encourages the developer to use Cordova API. So the answer is: use PhoneGap to access the Camera.